# Make a part of UILabel clickable

Tags: swift, uilabel

Hi Im new to swift and Im trying to have a part of UILabel open up a link in browser.I have created label in storyboard and type as attributed.Im sure how to make it clikable in the most easiest way possible. Also some time there are multiple links for different words but all are part of same label.

Comment: You need to apply two things- One is applied NSRange for a particular part that will clickable and second - for that label, apply user interaction enable

Comment: can u please elaborate. It would be helpful if you could give some code

Comment: The easiest way? Use a `UITextView`. `UILabel` isn't done for that, `UITextView` is. A few lines will modify the aspect of a `UITextView` that will make it a `UILabel` and the user won't even see the difference. There are plenty of question on SO about that, did you try them?

Comment: @GeethanjaliReddy Just applied userinteraction enable for the range, where you want clickable- Exmple- **myMutableString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 125.0/255.0, blue: 179.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), range: NSRange(location:0,length:5))**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I achieved this was by using tttatributed label.

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement there are two possible ways

1. User `UITextView` and mark his `Link property`

[image]

It will automatically styling the URLs to hyperlink and when you press them it will open them.

2. The other way is to use `WKWebView` and show all your data to webview. `WKWebView` automatically show hyperlinks and when you click them it will open the detail page.

Comment: here im using a UILabel

Comment: If there will only url then we can easily handle with uilabel but as you stated multiple urls can also come so you need to change your UI element form UILabel to UITextView or something else.